# Which regex expression in python would work on this text?

Tags: python, regex, list, strip

```
> 1. string string2021-05-13T08:58:05.495string string string2. string string2021-05-13T08:58:18.443string string string3.string....
```

I want to separate the datatime stamp and the number followed by dot from the strings (strings don't have an extact lenght) and store this values in a list of lists

```
[[1. string string 
2021-05-13T08:58:05.495 
string string string]

[2. string string
2021-05-13T08:58:18.443
string string string]

[3. string....]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try
`[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}`

You can verify if your regexes works there: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Regex should work as shown here: https://regex101.com/r/71Y676/1
Question is, how do you use it?

Comment: I used with strip() method, is that right??

Comment: It worked with replace(), thanks!!